# Zero sized array warning for array of length 1

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I have this code:

```
template<char... c>
struct StaticStringConst
{
    const char cstr[] = {c...,0};
};
```

Compiling under g++ 5.1.0 I get the following error:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'cstr' [-Wpedantic]
```

It seems to me that my array is actually never zero...so what is going on here?

Comment: gcc 7.1.1 has a more helpful error message: `warning: ISO C++ forbids flexible array member 'cstr' [-Wpedantic]`

Comment: @Rakete1111 But to my understanding this is a fixed size array...correct?

Comment: That is a fixed sized array, it's just that its bounds aren't being deduced. If you replace the line with: `const char cstr[sizeof...(c) + 1] = {c...,0};` it should work.

Comment: @Rakete1111: That's not really more helpful. It's just a different wording for the same thing.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It's more helpful in the sense that it doesn't say that `cstr` has a size of zero.

Comment: Hmm. It seems like it ought to compile. What does clang say about it?

Comment: @Rakete1111: But flexible array members *do* have a size of zero. It would be more helpful if it said something like `array bound cannot be deduced from an in-class initializer`, which is what clang says.

Comment: @RichardHodges It does compile....it gives a warning though

Comment: [Flexible array member in C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

Comment: fyi Template not needed: `struct foo { const char cstr[] = {'a', 'b'}; };` same issue.  g++ 5.1.0